# Excel JavaScript API open a file

Tags: xlsx, excel-addins

I have a excel file on my server,such as "http://oss.sheetjs.com/test_files/formula_stress_test.xlsx",I want to open local Excel use Excel JavaScript API.
Please tell me ,Can I do it?

Comment: Here's a library that literally has everything you need for this `https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx`

Answer (score -1):

Will this help you to open the excel file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx");
  }
</script>
```

Here also have some example take a look [Example](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,This is very help to me.